# How to programatically add a datagrid to a stackpanel in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a stackpanel in my XAML called MainStackPanel.
Inside my XAML.CS I am programatically creating a few datagrids like this:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var datagrid = new DataGrid();
        // add some columns and stuff
    }
```

This is just an example, in reality I am creating a dozen or so (depending on the results from the database).

I need to add them to my stackpanel (defined in my XAML file as follows:

```
    <ScrollViewer Name="MainScrollViewer" Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel Name="MainStackPanel">
        // in here somehow
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

How can I programatically add my datagrids (in this case var datagrid) to the stackpanel (MainStackPanel)?
Thanks,

Comment: Do you add all the dozen datagrids to the same stackpanel at once?
or is it one at a time based on the context?

Comment: All at once ... I have a function that I call that loads the data from the DB and creates all the necessary datagrids from that

Comment: OK. `MainStackPanel.Children.Add(datagrid)` as mentioned in the answer below should help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MainStackPanel.Children.Add(datagrid);